# Will Wireless work if I upgrade to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, acer

I have tried 11.10 in the past and the wireless was not fixed.  Can someone please answer me a simple question and let me know when my Acer ZG8 will be able to run normally without a ton of command line functions.

Comment: difficult to say really - what is your wireless card? `lshw -class network` - have you tried booting from a live usb/cd to check compatibility?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a LIVE USB/CD/DVD version of the Ubuntu distro you want to test.  If your wireless works using a Live USB/CD/DVD you should be fine once you upgrade.

Comment: I have done that, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem I recently had with a solution **ManyRoads** gave was that Live CD version couldn't install driver for my wifi card by default- it had to be enabled with **Additional Drivers** in **Preferences** section in main menu. I could try to enable it but it needed... internet connection to download that driver first;) Connecting to router directly with LAN cable solved the problem. Maybe that helps...